# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - Web Client.Download

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, webclient

I am trying to download a json string from a web page. I have been using System.Net.WebClient.

When I run it, it works fine on the first loop through, however when it comes through a second time it throws this error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.
```

I have narrowed down the line of code that is causing this error and I am completely baffled by it as works fine on the first attempt but doesn't on the second.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var url = string.Format(@"{0}{1}", _partOne, partTwo);
    var result= client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

It is throwing the error on the following line specifically.

```
var result= client.DownloadString(url);
```

Just for more background this is a MVVM WPF application.

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MyApp.App.Main() in c:\MyApp\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
```

I forgot to mention that the error is thrown on this line then I am able to see that it did infact return the correct data but won't let me continue to the next line.

Comment: It has to be in the makeup of _partOne and/or partTwo.  What is their content at the moment of execution?

Comment: If that line is what throws the exception please provide _partOne and partTwo values (and, if it's a MVC controller method, its prototype). Moreover even exception stack trace may help...

Comment: I'm not able to provide the make up of the string but it is 100% correct.